# How to keep an EntityManager/Session open across multiple transactions in a single thread?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Is there any way to prevent spring data from closing the underlying hibernate session after an `@Transactional` method in a `@Service` component? I am writing a simple command line app that reads data from a web service, does some processing and writes to the database. Some of the operations span multiple entities and must be transactional.

However, I am running into too many `LazyLoadingExceptions`. Apparently the hibernate session is automatically closed by spring after the transaction commits.

In other words, what I am trying to achieve is something like `OpenSessionInView`, but for a command line app. I could achieve this by using pure JPA and manually handling the entity manager and transactions. However, I would like to know if is there a solution which enables to leverage the spring-data and still achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: In spring boot by default `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`. This enables what you are calling OpenSessionInView, unless you have made it false explicitly.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu this is a command line app, not running on a web context